# Rails Validation with if Condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

I just found the following line of code in a project I'm working on at my new employer:

```
validates :message, presence: true, if: :message
```

Am I missing something, or is this pointless?

It seems that it's validating the presence of the message, but only in the case that the message is set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Validates is uses for Model level validation.

---

### validates :message, presence: true

means you have to insert atleast one character.
If you are entering message on view then it is pointless to use if condition.

Answer (score 0):

i assume this was used by someone who did not know about the `allow_blank: true` option. but this is a case for when you should use a comment on your code...

Comment: But still... Having a presence validator and then adding `allow_blank: true` seems pointless.